# How do I build a function that that returns a max number without using any built-in functions

Tags: python, function, return, max

I am trying to build a simple function that returns a max number without any built-in functions, arrays or a `list`.
Attached image to my error.

I created a function with (a ,b, c) for 3 numbers.
I defined all of them and tried to return the max number but I get " b not defined error".

Comment: There is no "attached image" but we don't want images of code anyway.  Edit your question and add the code *as text* that produces the error claimed.

Comment: You don't give the code, we can't read your mind.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 4):

### If we take the question literally....

In order to completely avoid calling any built-in functions and use neither `array` nor `list` we can implement it recursively:

```
def find_maximum(*l):
    if l[:2] == l[:1]: # Hack to avoid calling `len`
        return l[0]  # Base case: Only one element, return it as the maximum
    else:
        sub_max = find_maximum(*l[1:])  
        return l[0] if l[0] > sub_max else sub_max  

maximum = find_maximum(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

This implementation *technically* doesn't use either `array`s or `list`s because `type(l) == <class 'tuple'>`.

Another possible solution if the question really concerns the maximum of three variables :

```
fun = lambda a, b ,c : a if a>b and a>c  else b if b>c else c
assert fun(1,2,3) == 3
assert fun(1,3,2) == 3
assert fun(2,3,1) == 3
assert fun(2,1,3) == 3
```

The better way to achieve it is with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce


l = list(range(10))
reduce(lambda a, b: a if a > b else b, l)
```

Output:

```
9
```

Comment: `reduce` is a built-in function, both in the sense that it's accessed from the standard library *and* that it really is built-in to the implementation. (It just isn't bound to a name in the built-in scope like it was in Python 2.)

Comment: You're also using a list, another thing prohibited in the question.

Comment: Thanks! Helpful comments, I edited my answer. I still think that the spirit of the question is best answered by the first version, while the literal question is answered by the last version.

Comment: While your last one technically uses tuples instead of lists, I suspect the intent of the assignment was to look at direct comparisons between three individual items `a`, `b`, and `c`. (Basically, construct a search tree using nested `if` statements.) (Or maybe not; the OP's referenced "function with (a, b, c)" might just be their attempt to solve a special case.)

Comment: I thought complying with the literal question would be a fun challenge, rather than solving specifically `lambda a,b,c : a if a>b and a>c  else b if b>c else c`:(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `try` and `except` don't count as "built-in functions," and building off @Sebastian Wozny's observation that `tuple`s aren't lists:

```
# The asterisk before the parameter name indicates a variadic function:
# any number of arguments can be passed to this function.
def findMax(*n):
    maxSoFar = None
    atIndex = 0
    while True:
        # Without being able to use the built-in 'len' function, we have to 'try'
        # each index value in the arguments tuple until we get an out-of-bounds error
        try:
            if (maxSoFar == None) or (n[atIndex] > maxSoFar):
                maxSoFar = n[atIndex]
            atIndex += 1
        except IndexError:
            # When we DO get an out-of-bounds error, that means every number
            # has been compared and we're done!  Return maxSoFar, which is now
            # equal to the true maximum of all the inputs.
            return maxSoFar
        
maxNumber = findMax(5, 2, 3, 10, 8, 7, 1, 12, 3, 5, 12, 11, 4)
print(maxNumber) # prints 12
```

This can find the maximum of any number of numbers.

Comment: love the "easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission" attitude, although you are *technically* using `print`, which is a built-in

Comment: @SebastianWozny Thanks!  printing the result is optional though- I only did it to show the output is correct

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
def get_max(arr):
    _max = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if _max < arr[i]:
            _max = arr[i]
    return _max
```